# No version attribute when install OR-tools

Tags: python, ubuntu, or-tools

I'm trying to install OR-tools on Linux for Python, an optimization library by Google. 
https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/installing.html#unix_binary

I'm using a freshly downloaded VM (Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak from OS boxes), so I doubt my system is the issue (unless ofc I haven't installed something I need).

I also doubt OR-tools is the issue. I've nothing to the VM except:

sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install g++
downloaded Python—tar.gz, extracted in Downloads
run "make install" after cding into Downloads

I get an error "You are using a ortools module that doesn't have a version attribute". Does anyone know what this might mean?

I've tried the two tips suggested by the command prompt:

Running /usr/bin/python setup.py install --user works, but the error "warning: install_lib: 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' does not exist -- no Python modules to install" pops up.

Removing the init.pyc file tells me to remove the init.py file, and then it says or-tools isn't found.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated, still learning Linux so I'm sure I'm doing something dumb....

Full output of make install:

```
python setup.py install --user
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to ortools_examples.egg-info/requires.txt
writing ortools_examples.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to ortools_examples.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to ortools_examples.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'ortools_examples.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'ortools_examples.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' does not exist -- no            Python modules to install
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying ortools_examples.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying ortools_examples.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying ortools_examples.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying ortools_examples.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying ortools_examples.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/ortools_examples-6.0.4217-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing ortools_examples-6.0.4217-py2.7.egg
Removing /home/osboxes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ortools_examples-6.0.4217-py2.7.egg
Copying ortools_examples-6.0.4217-py2.7.egg to /home/osboxes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ortools-examples 6.0.4217 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installed /home/osboxes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ortools_examples-6.0.4217-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for ortools-examples==6.0.4217
Searching for ortools==6.0.4217
Best match: ortools 6.0.4217
Processing ortools-6.0.4217-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
ortools 6.0.4217 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Using /home/osboxes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ortools-6.0.4217-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Searching for protobuf==3.2.0
Best match: protobuf 3.2.0
Processing protobuf-3.2.0-py2.7.egg
protobuf 3.2.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Using /home/osboxes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/protobuf-3.2.0-py2.7.egg
Searching for setuptools==26.1.1
Best match: setuptools 26.1.1
Adding setuptools 26.1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing easy_install script to /home/osboxes/.local/bin
Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for six==1.10.0
Best match: six 1.10.0
Processing six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
six 1.10.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Using /home/osboxes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for ortools-examples==6.0.4217
python check_python_deps.py --log=ERROR
[ERROR] You are using a ortools module that doesn't have a version attribute : /home/osboxes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ortools-6.0.4217-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ortools/init.pyc"
Run "/usr/bin/python setup.py install --user" to upgrade.
If the problem persists, remove the site-package that contains "/home/osboxes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ortools-6.0.4217-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ortools/init.pyc". You can do so either manually or by using pip.
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [troubleshooting page of the Google or-tools project](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/installing#troubleshooting), where this error is elaborated on:

> This occurs when you try to install a binary distribution, but the
>   installer is unable to build the ortools package for your operating
>   system. In this case, you can still install and run OR-Tools from
>   source files, and even build the python package yourself. You can do
>   so, by following these steps:
>
> - Install and compile OR-Tools as described in Linux/Mac OS X source installation or Windows source installation.
> - Don't forget to make sure that everything is working fine by running make test.
> - Run make pypi_archive. You will find the package under a directory called temp.

For me personally, building from the source files on my Ubuntu 16.04 VM did not work either (probably due to some error caused by virtualisation).

However, I found [this Python .egg file on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ortools-ubuntu-16.04/6.3.4431) for or-tools on Ubuntu 16.04, which is fairly easy to install with `easy_install <filename>.egg` (make sure to download Python setuptools first with `pip install setuptools`).

They have [these easy to install versions available for other versions of Ubuntu](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=ortools-&submit=search) than yours, like 16.04 and 17.04. In case you are upgrading soon, you might want to try one of those. Otherwise, you can try to `easy_install` an OS-unspecific version .egg file.

Comment: This issue isn't on the live version, it was fixed. See [or-tools issues on github](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/384)